# Area between $5 \, x \, \ln(x)$ and $(x+2) \, \ln(x)$

Tags: integration

Can someone help me with this?
I have already found their intersections

$$x = \frac{1}{2} \hspace{4mm} \text{and} \hspace{4mm} x = 1.$$
I did this:
$$\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1} (5x\ln(x) - (x+2)\ln(x)) \, \mathrm d x$$
I conclude in:
$$ 2 \int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1} ((x^2 - x) \, \ln(x) - (x^2 -x)) \, \mathrm d x $$
and I get $$ \frac{\ln({\frac{1}{2}}) - 1}{2}$$

but it's not the same that wolfram alpha shows [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=area+between+y%3D5*x*ln(x)+and+y%3D(x%2B2)*ln(x)+from+1%2F2+to+1).

Comment: It would be much better if you type your solution here so we can spot the error if there's any

Comment: You can check that your answer is wrong without WolframAlpha, e.g. in an exam, because it is negative and an area should be positive. Review all the steps.

Comment: Hint: Integral $ln(x)$ and $x ln(x)$ can both be evaluated through the integration by parts method.

Comment: Could you show the antiderivative you obtained ?

Comment: Although it's shouldn't be that big of an issue (x+2) ln x is on top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it is seen from the graph that $(x+2)\ln x \geq 5x\ln x$ over $[0.5,1]$. Thus we have to find, $$\int_{0.5}^{1} (x+2)\ln x - 5\ln x \mathrm{d}x$$ $$= \int_{0.5}^{1} 2\ln x - 4x\ln x \mathrm{d}x$$ $$=\int_{0.5}^{1} -2(2x-1)\ln x \mathrm{d}x$$ $$= [-2(x^2-x)\ln x]|_{0.5}^{1} + 2\int_{0.5}^{1} (x-1) \mathrm{d}x$$ $$=\frac{1}{2}[\ln 2 -\frac{1}{2}] = \frac{1}{4}[\ln 4-1]$$

Hope it helps.

Comment: how did you get $ln(2)$ ?

Comment: @JuanIgnacioCuiule We have $\ln 0.5 = \ln 1 -\ln 2 = -\ln 2$.

Comment: Oh thanks now I get it

Answer (score 2):

Well, the two intersections can be found by solving:

$$5x\ln\left(x\right)=\left(x+2\right)\ln\left(x\right)\space\Longleftrightarrow\space x=\frac{1}{2}\space\space\space\bigvee\space\space\space x=1\tag1$$

So, now in order to find the area between the two curves:

- $$\mathcal{A}_1=\int_\frac{1}{2}^15x\ln\left(x\right)\space\text{d}x=\frac{5\left(\ln\left(4\right)-3\right)}{16}\tag2$$
- $$\mathcal{A}_2=\int_\frac{1}{2}^1\left(x+2\right)\ln\left(x\right)\space\text{d}x=\frac{19}{16}-\frac{9\ln2}{8}\tag3$$

So, we get:

$$\mathcal{A}=\mathcal{A}_2-\mathcal{A}_1=\frac{19}{16}-\frac{9\ln2}{8}-\frac{5\left(\ln\left(4\right)-3\right)}{16}=\frac{\ln\left(4\right)-1}{4}\tag4$$